# How do you evaluate this limit? $\ln({x^3+2x^2+x})+ \frac{2}{x}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

How do you evaluate the following?

$$\lim_{x \to 0^+} \left [ \ln({x^3+2x^2+x})+ \frac{2}{x} \right ]$$

If I plug in $x$, I get $\infty-\infty$, which is undetermined, and I haven't been able to get the limit at a more manageable form. Can you please help me?

Comment: You don't get $\infty -\infty$.

Comment: @GitGud: it certainly looks like $-\infty+\infty$ to me...

Comment: @abiessu I'm stunned, I could swear the question had $\color{red}-\frac 2 x$.

Comment: Have you tried re-forming it to $$\frac {x\ln(x^3+2x^2+x)+2}{x}=\frac {x\ln(e^\frac 2x(x^3+2x^2+x))}{x}$$

Comment: it is indeed $-\infty+\infty$, sorry about that. @abiessu, I   tries that, and I stumbled upon the $\infty*0$. How do you deal with that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\ln(x^3 + 2x^2 + x) + \dfrac{2}{x} = -ln\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right) + 2\ln(x+1) + \dfrac{2}{x} = \dfrac{1}{x} + 2\ln(x+1) + y\left(1 - \dfrac{lny}{y}\right) \to +\infty$ as $y = \dfrac{1}{x} \to +\infty$ when $x \to 0^+$, and $\dfrac{lny}{y} \to 0$.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't quite get it. How did you get that $-\ln{\frac{1}{x}}$?

Comment: $\ln x = -\ln\frac 1x$

Comment: And the, where has that $\frac{2}{x} $ gone?

Comment: @BarbuDorel: 2/x = 1/x + y

Comment: When I type this function in the TI, it doesn't show the origin as a limit, it tends to give me infinity...

Comment: @imranfat: true....

Comment: Ok, I am now trying to understand your solution. Thank you!

Comment: @BarbuDorel: Just observe, to understand the process from the opposite direction, that: $$\frac{1}{x} + y \left ( 1 - \frac{\ln y}{y} \right ) = \frac{1}{x} + y - \ln y = \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{x} - \ln \frac{1}{x} = -\ln \frac{1}{x} + \frac{2}{x}$$

Comment: I got it, LAcarguy, thank you!

Comment: @BarbuDorel: cheers...

Answer (score 0):

Lets put $x = 1/y$ so that $y \to \infty$ as $x \to 0^{+}$. Then we can see that
\begin{align}
f(x) &= \log(x^{3} + 2x^{2} + x) + \frac{2}{x}\notag\\
&= \log\left(e^{2y}\left(\frac{1}{y^{3}} + \frac{2}{y^{2}} + \frac{1}{y}\right)\right)\notag\\
&> \log\left(e^{2y}\left(\frac{1}{y^{3}} + \frac{2}{y^{3}} + \frac{1}{y^{3}}\right)\right)\notag\\
&= \log\left(\frac{4e^{2y}}{y^{3}}\right)\tag{1}
\end{align}

Next we can see that $e^{t} \geq 1 + t > t$ for all $t$. And therefore $(e^{t})^{4} > t^{4}$. Putting $t = y/2$ we can see that $$e^{2y} > \frac{y^{4}}{16}\tag{2}$$ It follows from $(1)$ and $(2)$ that $$f(x) > \log\left(\frac{y}{4}\right)$$ Since $y \to \infty$ it follows that $\log(y/4) \to \infty$ and hence $f(x) \to \infty$ as $x \to 0^{+}$.